# Is there a way to invoke firebase callable could functions from Google Endpoints

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-endpoints

Endpoints can be used to invoke http cloud functions via ESP, is there a way to do the same for Callable cloud functions, since callable cloud functions are invoked via firebase client sdk.

Comment: Have a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference. «An https.onCall trigger for Cloud Functions is an HTTPS trigger with a specific format for the request and response.»

Answer (score 0):

Cloud functions can be deployed using Cloud CLI and Firebase CLI. The two CLI serve mostly different needs and deployment configuration are different [link](https://medium.com/google-developers/firebase-google-cloud-whats-different-with-cloud-functions-612d9e1e89cb). Firebase provids a wrapper around normal HTTP functions named "callable" functions. According to the documentation: "
It's important to keep in mind that HTTPS callable functions are similar but not identical to HTTP functions. To use HTTPS callable functions you must use the client SDK for your platform together with the functions.https backend API (or implement the protocol)" [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).

Comment: thank you very much for your feedback. I was wondering since callable functions trigger via client SDK, is there a way to secure it via ESP, so we could do stuff like rate-limit

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you can deploy a single product (Cloud Functions) with different tools. So, I think it is possible to secure a callable cloud function via ESP, but I could not find any example.

Comment: Yes I also didn't come across a proper example